# Custom Razor component a NuGet library behaves differently?

Tags: nuget, blazor-server-side, razor-components

I created 3 components which have the exact same implementation with only 1 difference:

- The 1st component (**MyTest**) is implemented in the same project as its parent component
- The 2nd one (**Component1**) is from a different (but same solution)
- The 3rd (**CSInput**) is imported from a NuGet package.  Below are the invokation of all 3 in the same parent.

The razor component implementation is as followed:

```
<input disabled="@Disabled">

@code {
 [Parameter]
 public bool Disabled { get; set; }
}
```

The snippet of the parent implementation:

```
// The Disabled property is coded as boolean
<MyTest Disabled="@DisableMyTest"/>
<RazorClassLibrary1.Component1 Disabled="@DisableMyTest" />
<CSInput Disabled="@DisableMyTest"/>

@code{
  private bool DisableMyTest = false;
}
```

For an unknown reason, the compiler issued a **CS1503 (cannot convert from 'bool' to 'string') on the Disabled property from CSInput**.  Any idea why?  Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out.  The weird behavior is caused by me not incrementing the version of the nuget.  Whenever you install a Nuget, VS keeps a copy of it in the .nuget\packages directory.  If you don't clean up that directory, VS will keep use what it has.  Now, where can I get wig....